# Image upload from one source in magento2?

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I'm searching for a possibility to replace the image upload of local files with another source like 3S of AWS or an FTP. It should be just one other source - our product manager shouldn't be able to select between several sources.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that add an abstract file layer between the system and the files. It is called flysystem and is used also in laravel the php framework. You can have different adapters e.g. local, sftp, dropbox, aws s3 and many more. Check the [flysystem website](http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/).

We created a module that integrates the flysystem library into magento2. You can also use the adapters on code level. That means it does not matter where your files are. With the module you also have one file-pool and do not need to upload the same image many times.

Check the [wiki for magento2 flysystem module](https://github.com/Flagbit/Magento2-Flysystem/wiki).